# Load content dynamically & resize event

Tags: javascript

On complex layouts, heavy use of Media Queries affect performances since the mobile browser still loads all elements that has been hidden.

For what I understand now, to load the right layout/content at the right moment (screen-size/device) we should use javascript.

I'm working on a template that should turn into a mobile version when the screen width is less than 1080px.
To do this I was thinking to combine Modernizr.mq with a resize event listener.

Do you know a better approach?

My modernizr code so far: http://jsfiddle.net/c4BcR/

Comment: The http://wicky.nillia.ms/enquire.js/ js will help you to achieve this.

Comment: yes that is another solution, but what are the advantages over modernizr?

Comment: [This](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/108882/run-shortcode-at-certain-resolution/108923#108923) is not a right answer for your question but can give you a direction

Comment: I'm implementing enquire.js, the only thing that I don't understand atm is how to serve the actual template parts my theme is made of, through js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember that PHP (wordpress) run on server, javascript run on browser.

So, what you intend is:

1. load an url of your site (a GET request is sended to server)
2. Server respond with a minimal html containing `enquire.js` and your script with `enquire.register` stuff
3. `enquire.js` recognize resolution and run a js function
4. the function triggered by `enquire.js` run an ajax call (this is a second request to server)
5. Server respond to the ajax call with the html from your template and using jquery.html() you put the html in the body of page. If want avoid loading jquery you can output json from server and use a pure js templating engine e.g. [Pure](http://beebole.com/pure/) to convert json to html in the body.

Is this optimized? **Not** for me.

- For every page load you run 2 server requests instead of one
- On the first request you need some scripts (enquire.js, your enquire.register script, jquery or templating script) that do nothing in the page, only scope is loading the content
- even if jquery or templating script are fast, static html outputted from server is always shown faster

In short, you do a lot of work to optimize site for mobile devices, with chances to get the **opposite** result.

This workflow can be useful for small parts of site, not for entire content. At least, not for me.

For me, in that case, I'd

1. for every template file create 3 versions, e.g. `page.php` | `page-tablet.php` | `page-phone.php` or `header.php` | `header-tablet.php` | `header-phone.php` and so on
2. On init, use a server detection method, like [Mobile Detect](http://mobiledetect.net/) to sniff the current device, put it in a static variable class or in a constant
3. Add a hook for `template_include` filter that append `"-{$device}"` to every template required. (e.g. if is required 'page.php' it returns 'page-tablet.php' if current device is a tablet)
4. Using the same `$device` global accessible variable, register js scripts *related* to the device
5. In the template file use `get_header($device)` instead of `get_header()` just like `get_footer($device)`, `get_sidebar($device)`. Also use `get_template_part('part', $device)` instead of `get_template_part('part')` and so on.

In this way you have

- one request per page and not 2
- every device load its own content
- html output is demanded to server and not to client, and this is better for performance

For little parts you can use the `enquire.js` method and flavor everything with some media queries. E.g. for tablets you can use the same template of desktops and use `enquire.js` + ajax to add some content if resolution is over a certain breakpoint.

Working with wordpress, in my opinion, this is the best way to get mobile optimized version of a site.

Comment: Cool stuff, thank you Giuseppe! I really understand your point. Mobile detection is exactly what I'm using right now but the customer -NOW- want the mobile template to pop up when the screen is smaller than 1080px. Is it possible to combine enquire.js with your solution?

Comment: In my scenario the layout and the content of the desktop version is too complex to hide it and retouch it with media queries. This is what I'm talking about: http://goo.gl/R54cre In this case I really need to load the mobile template when the screen width hits that size

Comment: @AndreaPuiatti, only for mobile devices under 1080px or all devices under 1080px? Outhere there are a lot of desktops with < 1080px resolution (1024) and a lot of mobile with > 1080 resolution. Using resolution is not targeting device. A large screen phone, (with a mobile connection) will download desktop version with chances to wait a looong time.

Comment: @AndreaPuiatti If possible, a good choice can be create a splash page and when you click the 'Enter Now' button you will open the right version (> 1080px or < 1080px) using a query var enqueued in the button link url using `enqueue.js`

Comment: @AndreaPuiatti my solution + enqueue.js is possible, but if mobile detect sniff a mobile device enqueue.js run on mobile version... I don't know if is good for you

Comment: The mobile version should be available to all mobile devices and all devices < 1080px. Btw. to load template parts with enquire.js I must use ajax anyway, am I wrong? Link: http://wicky.nillia.ms/enquire.js/#walkthrough

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/10315/discussion-between-g-m-and-andrea-puiatti)